# An easy way to center text between first and last non-white word in vim?

Tags: vim, macros, center

Is there an easy way using a macro or ~10 line function (no plugin!) to center some text between the first and last word (=sequence of non-blank characters) on a line?  E.g. to turn

```
        >>> No user serviceable parts below.               <<<
```

into

```
        >>>       No user serviceable parts below.         <<<
```

by balancing the spaces +/-1? You can assume no tabs and the result should not contain tabs, but note that the first word may not start in column 1. (EDIT: ... in fact, both delimiter words as well as the start and end of the text to center may be on arbitrary columns.)

Comment: Is there a fixed width?

Comment: @jacobwalker0814 No fixed width. romainl: I tried `:help center` and looked for plugins, but for such a simple task a plugin appears overkill.

Comment: @romainl I thought of using an external filter program, like writing a perl one-liner, but that's inelegant when there should be a vim-internal solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

source this function:

```
fun! CenterInSpaces()
    let l   = getline('.')
    let lre = '\v^\s*\S+\zs\s*\ze'
    let rre = '\v\zs\s*\ze\S+\s*$'
    let sp  = matchstr(l,lre)
    let sp  = sp.matchstr(l,rre)
    let ln  = len(sp)
    let l   = substitute(l,lre,sp[:ln/2-1],'')
    let l   = substitute(l,rre,sp[ln/2:],'')
    call setline('.',l)
endf
```

**note**

- this function might **NOT** work in all cases. I just wrote it quick for usual case. this is not a plugin after all
- the codes lines could be reduced by combining function calls. but i think it is clear in this way, so I just leave it like this.
- if it worked for you, you could create a map
- it works like this: (last two lines I typed `@:` to repeat cmd call)

[image]

Comment: Awesome. How did you generate the gif?

Comment: Superb, and it's only *nine* lines :-)

Comment: Can the two `getline('.')` calls in the assignments to `sp` be replaced with `l`?

Comment: @Jens you are right, I just cp/paste, without too much thinking, I will fix it

Comment: I too like your gif. I am a bit jealous my answer doesn't have one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:s` command with the `\=` aka sub-replace-expression.

```
:s#\v^\s*\S+\zs(\s+)(.{-})(\s+)\ze\S+\s*$#\=substitute(submatch(1).submatch(3),'\v^(\s*)(\1\s=)$','\1'.escape(submatch(2),'~&\').'\2','')#
```

**Overview**

Capture the text (including white-space) between the `>>>` and `<<<` marks. Divide up the white-space on both sides of the text in half and substitute in the non-white-space text in between. This white-space balancing act is done via the regex engine's backtracking because math is hard. Lets go shopping!

Notes:

- using `\v` or `very magic` mode to reduce escaping as this command is long enough 
  already
- use `#` as an alternative separator instead of the usual `/` for `:s/pat/sub/` in hopes to make it slightly more readable

**Matching Pattern**

```
:s#\v^\s*\S+\zs(\s+)(.{-})(\s+)\ze\S+\s*$#...
```

- `:s` with no range supplied only do the substitution on the current line.
- `^\s*\S+` match the starting white-space followed by non-white-space. `>>>` in this case.
- `(\s+)(.{-})(\s+)` match white-space followed by the "text" followed by white-space
- 3 capture groups: 1) leading white-space, 2) the "text", and 3) trailing white-space. These will be later referenced by `submatch(1)`, `submatch(2)`, and `submatch(3)` respectively
- `.{-}` is vim-speak for non-greedy matching or `.*?` in perl-speak
- without the non-greedy matching the second capture group would include too much white-space at its end
- `\S+\s*$` match the non-white-space (i.e. `<<<`) and any trailing white-space
- Use `\zs` and `ze` to designate the start and end of the match to be replaced

**Replacement**

```
\=substitute(submatch(1).submatch(3),'\v^(\s*)(\1\s=)$','\1'.escape(submatch(2),'~&\').'\2','')
```

- `\=` tells vim that replacement will be a vim expression. Also allows the use of `submatch()` functions
- `substitute({str}, {pat}, {sub}, {flags})` Our expression will be a nested substitution
- `substitute(submatch(1).submatch(3), ...)` do a substitute over the concatenation of leading and trailing white-spacing captured in `submatch(1)` and `submatch(3)`
- The `{pat}` is `^(\s*)(\1\s=)$`. Match some white-space followed by white-space of the same length as the first or 1 character longer. Capture both halves.
- `escape(submatch(2),'~&\')` escape `submatch(2)` for any special characters. e.g. `~`,`&`,`\1`, ...
- The `{sub}` is `'\1'.escape(submatch(2),'~&\').'\2'`. Replace with the the escaped `submatch(2)` (i.e. the "text" we want to center) in between the halves of white-space, `\1` and `\2` from the `{pat}`
- No `{flag}`'s are needed so `''`

**Usage**

If you use this often I would suggest creating a command and putting it in `~/.vimrc`.

```
command! -range -bar -nargs=0 CenterBetween <line1>,<line2>s#\v^\s*\S+\zs(\s+)(.{-})(\s+)\ze\S+\s*$#\=substitute(submatch(1).submatch(3),'\v^(\s*)(\1\s=)$','\1'.submatch(2).'\2','')#`
```

Otherwise use this once and then repeat the last substitution via `&` on each needed line.

**For more help see**

```
:h :s/
:h :s/\=
:h sub-replace-\=
:h submatch(
:h substitute(
:h escape(
:h /\v
:h /\S
:h /\{-
:h /\zs
:h &
```

**EDIT by Kent**

Don't be jealous, your answer has it too. ^_^

I didn't change the command, just cp/paste to my vim. only add `|noh` at the end to disable highlighting.

If execute this command, it looks like:

[image]

Comment: +1 I didn't notice this answer. nice substitution. btw, I made a gif for you.. will edit your answer and add it soon, remove it if you don't like. :)

Comment: Thank you. I will have to learn how to make those gifs one day.

Comment: you don't have to learn, just a small tool. google byzanz, you will see, it's really easy to use.

Comment: Holy biscuits that is nice! Sadly I use windows here at work. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any good way. I usually do it in a semi-automatic way, by using `:center` on a line of text that only contains the parts that are to be centered and then move the result into the line containing the surrounding parts.

If nobody else has a better answer, perhaps [boxes](http://boxes.thomasjensen.com/) can help if you need to do this kind of thing a lot.